# How to display a report by Department wise

Tags: crystal-reports

How to display a report by Department wise

Using Crystal Report 8.5

```
ID Name Department

001 raja IT
002 Vijay IT
003 Ram CSE
So on...
```

Display an Each Page by Department wise.

Once IT Department is completed then go to new page and display CSE Department, like that I need.

How to make in crystal report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like others have said. Create a group for the Department field. Go to the section expert for the group footer, enter this into the "New Page After" formula.

```
not onlastrecord
```

this will prevent the blank last page.

Comment: +1 Gopal is notorious for not upvoting his accepted answers so I'll do it for him. :)

Answer (score 1):

Insert -> Group -> Department.

Once you have a group section, right click on it. It should show you checkboxes on right side which should have an option which could be "print on new page".

See if that helps.

Comment: I can't able find "print on new page" option

Comment: +1 on this answer because judging from your other recent questions I think you are looking to do this in Crystal. 

In the Section Expert you can click on the section and either check the "New Page Before" or "New Page After" to display the section on a new page.

Answer (score 0):

use sql group by department

Answer (score 0):

Add group in the crystal report or use group by in the Sql query like that is is possible
and set every group comes in the new page in th section expert->select group section and set new page after.